# Combining bounds in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, concentration-of-measure

Consider events $A, B$. Let $X,Y$ be random variables for which we want to determine a concentration inequality of the form $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|\geq \varepsilon) \leq c \exp(-C)$
for some constants $c,C$ which may depend on $\varepsilon > 0$.

Now, assume we know that on $A$, we can bound $|X-Y| \leq |Z| + |W|$. Additionally, we know that on the event $B$ we have that $|Z| \leq \delta$ and $|W| \leq \rho$ for some constants $\delta, \rho > 0$.

Is there a way to combine these two known facts to get a general concentration result? Assume we know both $\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)$. Proof strategies I have seen using bounds in probability never include two separate bounds, and I would like to know how to combine such results.

Comment: If $\delta+\rho<\varepsilon$ then one has $P(|X-Y|\ge\varepsilon) \le P(A^c\cup B^c)$. Does that help?

Comment: @Victor I think it helps a bit, how do you justify it?

Comment: $P(E)\le P(E\cap(A\cap B)) + (1-P(A\cap B))$ for any event $E$